# generator object into tab delimited text

Tags: python

I used a generator to create s

```
s= generator(n)
```

the generator yeilds (a,b) for n in a range(n). where a=[w,x] and b=[y,z]

printing s using

```
for i in s:
    print i
```

this returns:

```
([0.27704232355167768, 0.44459304959240675], [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683])
([0.27704232355167768, 0.44459304959240675], [0.6362447250743466, 0.72047209074359853])
([0.27704232355167768, 0.44459304959240675], [0.65419386891877318, 0.025362727486327286])
([0.27704232355167768, 0.44459304959240675], [0.039966264334369672, 0.9662795347591735])
```

However I would like

```
0.27704232355167768 0.44459304959240675 0.4387731877846518 0.38108111684466683
0.27704232355167768 0.44459304959240675 0.6362447250743466 0.72047209074359853
0.27704232355167768 0.44459304959240675 0.65419386891877318 0.025362727486327286
0.27704232355167768 0.44459304959240675 0.039966264334369672 0.9662795347591735
```

I have tried many variations of the idea below

```
print '\n'.join('\t'.join(x) for x in s)
```

but to n0 avail and tend to return the s in the same format.  Can anyone help me around this issue?

Comment: So what is `S`? `S` can't look like what you posted because there are no commas delimiting the separate entities. Is each line a separate generator?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post a working example, so that we can actually help you. Otherwise our answers will only be guesses.

Comment: Thanks guys Joel does the edit help you understand the format more?
@Rik I use more than one generator befpore I get to this part and so had not gone into this for simplicity maybe I mock example will help

Comment: A simple example that can reproduce your same output will be enough. That way we wont have to cook one up by ourselves. From here it looks like your generator is yeliding a tuple of list of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from itertools import chain
'\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,tuple(chain(*i)))) for i in s)
```

`chain` flattens each row, so you can just join all of the elements with a tab, then join rows with newline.

Comment: Hmmm im trying to write this to a text file now. So I also have been trying your code Marcin thank you. But it says string expected list found.

Comment: I think this is beacuae of the lack of map?

Comment: @user1320502 Yes, map to str needed.

Comment: Marcin thank you for this.  I found your code much easier to turn into a .txt file that had the appropriate formatting.
for anyone interested:

from itertools import chain
`open("data555.txt", "w").write('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,tuple(chain(*i)))) for i in s))`

Comment: @user1320502 I'm very glad to help! Note that you can, if you wish, switch acceptance of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> for i in s:
        print '\t'.join(map(str,chain(*i)))


0.277042323552 0.444593049592 0.438773187785 0.381081116845
0.277042323552 0.444593049592 0.636244725074 0.720472090744
0.277042323552 0.444593049592 0.654193868919 0.0253627274863
0.277042323552 0.444593049592 0.0399662643344 0.966279534759
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how your generator looks like, but looking at your example, if your generator is as below

```
>>> def generator(n):
    for i in xrange(0,n):
        yield ([0.27704232355167768, 0.44459304959240675], [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683])
    return
```

then you can something like

```
>>> s=generator(5)
>>> print '\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str,x))  for x in s)
[0.2770423235516777, 0.44459304959240675]   [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683]
[0.2770423235516777, 0.44459304959240675]   [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683]
[0.2770423235516777, 0.44459304959240675]   [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683]
[0.2770423235516777, 0.44459304959240675]   [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683]
[0.2770423235516777, 0.44459304959240675]   [0.4387731877846518, 0.38108111684466683]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you Abhijit I didnt want brackets but this may be useful format sometime in the future.